# Angular execute function on first key up and another function every key up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, haml

I'm trying to implement a typing game. Where you type a given word and it times you.

I'm stuck where I want to have a function call to start a timer as soon as the user begins typing.

Also, every time a user types I check the contents of an input box to see if they match the given word.

Here are my two functions:

```
$scope.SpellCheck = function() {
  if($scope.newEntry.name == $scope.entries[$scope.count].sentence) {
    $scope.count += 1;
    $scope.newEntry.name = '';
  }
} 

$scope.Start = function() {
  $scope.stopwatch = $timeout(function() {
    $scope.value++;
    Start();
  }, 100);
}
```

And my view

```
%div{ 'ng-controller' => 'TyperCtrl' }
  %form
    %input{'type' => 'text', 'autofocus' => 'true', 'ng-model'=>'newEntry.name', 'ng-keyup' => 'SpellCheck();Start();'}

  {{newEntry.name}}
  %h1
    {{value}}
  %br

  %ul
    %li
      {{entries[count].sentence}}
```

Right now calling both functions on a ng-keyup event causes the timer to only increment when someone is typing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set a flag that lets you know you've started typing. Clear it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about the logic of your stopwatch, but I would add a helper variable to your `Start()` method, set it when `Start()` is first called, then check against it whenever `Start()` is run. This way the stopwatch is started only once.

```
var stopwatchRunning = false;
$scope.Start = function() {
    if (!stopwatchRunning) {
        $scope.stopwatch = $timeout(function() {
            $scope.value++;
            Start();
        }, 100);
        stopwatchRunning = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried this. Because the timer works recursively it will stop incrementing value when I set stopwatchRunning to true. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Any advice on how I could reimplement the stopwatch?

Comment: How about using $interval instead of $timeout? That way it runs until you stop it.

Comment: thanks I'll look into that. From my understanding though interval starts a clock from maybe the current time. I guess then I would take the difference between stop and start time?

Comment: Sure, that could be one way to do it. Have it run every second, increment a scope variable by 1 (bound to something on the website to give the user info on how long he has currently taken), then when the correct word is typed stop the interval and calculate the total time used by subtracting one datetime from another.